# How to encrypt text with websites public key?

Tags: python, ssl, openssl

So I have spent many hours looking for the answer and thus far haven't been able to come up with anything. So if this is a repeat of another question then I apologize. 
I am wanting to get the public key from a website(lets say www.google.com for example) and use that to encrypt some text. I would like to do this with python. I have been trying out things that I have found online

```
hostname='www.google.com'
port=443

context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
ssl_sock = context.wrap_socket(s, server_hostname=hostname)
ssl_sock.connect((hostname, port))
ssl_sock.close()
print("ssl connection Done")

cert = ssl.get_server_certificate((hostname, port))
print(cert)
# OpenSSL
x509 = OpenSSL.crypto.load_certificate(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, cert)
print(x509)
pk = x509.get_pubkey()
print(pk)
key = OpenSSL.crypto.dump_publickey(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, pk)
print(key)
```

This is working as far as getting the certificate and extracting the public key. However I can't figure out how to use it to encrypt something. Some help would be greatly appreciated. I am not an expert at python yet.

Comment: This is probably too broad of a question to be well answered here. I would suggest using the [pyca/cryptography](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/) package along with pyOpenSSL. You can get the public key in a form that pyca/cryptography likes via [to_cryptography](https://pyopenssl.org/en/stable/api/crypto.html#OpenSSL.crypto.PKey.to_cryptography_key). Then you can experiment to your heart's content with these keys.

Comment: Awesome I will read up on that package and see where it takes me. Thanks for the help!